# Getting a parameter is incorrect error with TextWrapping property set to WrapWholeWords?

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, word-wrap

In my C#/WinRT app (Windows Store app) I have a TextBox.  I can set it's *TextWrapping* property to *Wrap* or *NoWrap* and it works.  But if I try to use the value of "WrapWholeWords" I get a design time error with the property value highlighted.  When I mouse over the error I get the error message "the parameter is incorrect" with the error code *E_RUNTIME_SETVALUE*.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it if I can?

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtNotes" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="TextBlock" Margin="30" FontSize="20"/>
```

The TextBox is hosted on a grid control if that matters.  Note, the *WrapWholeWords* value is offered by Intellisense from the XAML editor and from the Property Editor pane in the IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not allowed.

> TextBox and RichEditBox don't support the WrapWholeWords value for their TextWrapping properties. If you try to use WrapWholeWords as a value for TextBox.TextWrapping or RichEditBox.TextWrapping an invalid argument exception is thrown.

Above was copied from this link:
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textwrapping)

Comment: Thanks.  Because it was offered up as choice by Intellisense I wouldn't have thought that.  Sounds like Intellisense needs to be updated.